# Knockout Validation with throttle

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I just noticed that using the throttle extender causes Knockout Validation to stop working. Is there a way around this problem?

```
var viewModel = {
    label1: ko.observable('label1').extend({required: true}),
    label2: ko.observable('label2').extend({required: true, throttle: 1}),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rWqkC/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case the order of the extenders does matter because the `throttle` extender return a new `ko.dependentObservable` that's why if you have  the `required` first then it will apply on the wrong observable.

Change the order and it should work:

```
ko.observable('label2').extend({throttle: 500, required: true }),
```

But because the extender execution in the order of the property declaration isn't really defined you are safer if you use use two extends in this case:

```
ko.observable('label2').extend({throttle: 500}).extend({required: true })
```

[Demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bj6Y6/2/)

Comment: You can't rely on the order of the declarations, that isn't really defined.  It would be safer to put each extension in a separate `extend()` call.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this answer:

If you're using a Knockout version after 3.1.0, consider using the [rateLimit extender](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html). 
(rateLimit instead of throttle)